# VueJS: use computed "set/get" with Vue.Draggable and VueX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue.draggable

I'm seeking for a help with "Vue.Draggable".
The second day I`m trying to update draggable array correctly.

The challenge is:

- update draggable array using computed set/get functions
- get draggable item properties including information about parent item and call axios function to update data on a MySQL.

Data sample:

```
{ cat1: { authors: [ { name: "Name 1" }, { name: "Name 2" } ] }, cat2: { authors: [ { name: "Name 3" }, { name: "Name 4" } ] } }
```

Rendering code:

```
<div v-for="(category, index) in categories">
    <draggable v-bind:id="index" v-model="category.authors" :options="{group:'authorslist', draggable:'.author'}" class="draggable-row" >
    <div v-for="author in category.authors" :key="author.id" class="author" >
```

What I'm trying to do:

Actually, mentioned construction works fine. But only visually.
VueX gives an error about mutation process.

```
[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers." Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
```

Replacing `v-model` with `:value` helps but in this case, D&D is not working even visually.

I have tried a lot of variants... One  is - create a computed property for "categories" and use "get/set" functions to call `actions->mutations` from them. The problem is - `categories->set` function is not working when we are changing `authors` array structure.

The second problem is drag and drop `author` between `categories` in such a way it allows us to get author and category id to use it in an `Axios` query.

I was trying to use `@end` event BUT(!) it works for only a sorting process but not for D&D between parent elements (categories).

**I'll be very grateful for any help!**

Comment: Can you show us the error vuex is giving you?  That would help.

Comment: Hello Jim. Thanks for responding.
It gives errors only if I'm using "v-model" instead of ":value".

`[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."`
`Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.`

Comment: It's telling you the truth.  You shouldn't modify vuex state outside of a mutator.  We'll need to see more of your code to help, but suffice it to say you're not quite using vuex right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to avoid to directly mutate the store state, you should use a computed value and use store action. Something like:

```
<draggable :id="index" v-model="authors" :options="{group:'authorslist', draggable:'.author'}">
```

And:

```
computed:{
 authors: {
        get() {
            return this.$store.state.authors
        },
        set(value) {
            this.$store.commit('updateAuthors', value)
        }
    }
}
```